# HTML, jQuery, CSS - Width() returning entire page width instead of div on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to have a function apply "padding-bottom" in a div when a page is loaded, the only problem is that the width returns the entire document value instead of the div value. When I use another function (that changes between images) the function works fine.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.photoset').each(function () {
    $items = $(this).find('img')

    function get_height(target) {
      return (($items.eq(target).height() / $(this).width()) * 100) + '%';
     }
      $items.css({ paddingBottom: get_height(0) });
  });
}
```

The Css is as follow:

```
.photowrapper{
    width:60%;
    margin:auto;
}
.photoset {
    position: relative; 
    display: block;   
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.photoset figure{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
}

.photoset img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition:opacity 1.2s;
    max-width:100%;

}
.photoset .photoset-show img{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And the HTML

```
 <div class="photowrapper">
   <div class="photoset center-block">

    <figure class="photoset-show">
     <img src="/images/5220a574-77a8-4aa6-aecc-aedf60eed6e2.jpg" />
    </figure>
    <figure class="">
     <img src="/images/9e59af1e-de75-4ddb-b091-f816224d9f6e.jpg" />
    </figure>
    <figure class="">
      <img src="/images/ad76e5e3-5780-4f22-bcb4-8106fc41161a.jpg" />
    </figure>

 </div>
</div>
```

This function works as intended, it returns the right width value when switching between images:

```
        var showCurrent = function (photoset) {
        $items = photoset.find('figure');
        $images = photoset.find('img');
        var counter = photoset.data('counter');
        var numItems = $items.length;
        var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter % numItems);
        $items.each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('photoset-show');
        })
        function get_height(target) {
            return (($images.eq(target).height() / photoset.width()) * 100) + '%';
        }
        photoset.animate({ paddingBottom: get_height(itemToShow) }, 400);
        $items.eq(itemToShow).addClass('photoset-show');

    };
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` within `get_height` ?

Comment: @guest271314 It was supposed to be the `'.photoset'` div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` isn't what you think it is inside `get_height()`. It has a different context inside the function. Store a reference to `this` or pass it in as an argument

Try

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.photoset').each(function () {
    var $photoset = $(this), $items = $photoset.find('img')

    function get_height(target) {
      return (($items.eq(target).height() / $photoset.width()) * 100) + '%';
     }
      $items.css({ paddingBottom: get_height(0) });
  });
}
```

Comment: works amazingly! Care to explain what mine was returning? Thanks in advance.

Comment: also get in habit of always using `var` when declaring variables or you will run into unexpected results always putting variables in global namespace

Comment: simple enough to find out yourself ... `console.log(this)`